# Label in custom view not updating

Tags: ios

I have created a custom UIView in xib with class InfoPopUpView. I add it to my viewController. It works well and the Custom Class xib is set in the File's Owner.
I can set the titleLbl variable in my first viewcontroller no problem.

My problem appears when I in another viewcontroller want to use the InfoPopUpView again but with a different title...
The title does not change/update.  It is as if InfoPopUpView remembers the last title I set and dont care for changing it..

How can I initialise? the titleLbl variable in the InfoPopUpView Class so that I can change it later?

Any help is very much appreciated - thank you !

> ViewController

```
var popUpView: InfoPopUpView!
popUpView = InfoPopUpView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 268))
popUpView.titleLbl.text = "MyFirstTitle"
view.addSubview(popUpView)
```

> Custom Class

```
class InfoPopUpView: UIView {

    var view: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var okBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    @IBAction func didTapOkBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("popUpController", object: nil)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }


    func setup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)

    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "InfoPopUpView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: The 4 lines of code you have shown for the `ViewController` do not change the title?

Comment: @luk2302 No, it does not

Comment: @luk2302 I figured it out..  Thank you, your question actually put me on the right track..I was executing the code in the viewcontroller based on a notification.  When I posted a new notification I had forgotten to remove the prior observer, hence I also presented the prior popUpView

Comment: Okay, happy to help even if it was not much ;)

Comment: Really thank you so much :-)